# Streaming in Apache & Passenger

Tags: apache, passenger

Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
Server built:   Mar  4 2013 22:05:29

Phusion Passenger version 4.0.21

```
Alias /tester /var/www/tester/public
<Location /tester>
   PassengerBaseURI /tester
   PassengerAppRoot /var/www/tester
</Location>
<Directory /var/www/tester>
   Allow from all
   Options -MultiViews
   #Enable response streaming
   PassengerBufferResponse off
</Directory>
```

Hello,
I'm having a problem with 'streaming' while using Apache. If I try to run the following code, it completes the processing before it is sent to the client;

```
#app.rb
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  stream do |out|
   out << "foo\n"
  sleep 10
   out << "bar\n"
 end
end
```

If I run the app launching thin, sinatra, or passenger from the CLI, it will stream 'foo', then some time later will stream 'bar'.

Any idea why Apache is buffering the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a limitation in Sinatra. The Sinatra streaming API only supports EventMachine-based servers, which Phusion Passenger is not. Do not use the Sinatra streaming API; instead, use the low-level Rack APIs directly to implement streaming. You can use [the Rack socket hijacking API](http://blog.phusion.nl/2013/01/23/the-new-rack-socket-hijacking-api/) for this purpose, to send raw HTTP responses over the socket.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Before I go down that rabbit hole; I choose Passenger because it seemed like a robust server. I am new to the Ruby/Rails/Padrino scene, and usually work on Windows systems. Trying to serve Ruby on IIS, or even Apache on Windows doesn't work.

Can you suggest a better platform that I should build a server out of to simplify things? I will be hosting multiple sites and most apps will be Padrino-based, but some Rails.

I am also a little confused as to why launching 'passenger start' to run the Sinatra app without going through Apache will serve the pages properly?

Comment: Passenger has 3 modes which are totally separate from each other. Those are: the Apache mode, the Nginx mode and the standalone mode. 'Passenger start' runs the standalone mode only. This is described in the manual.